# Linear operator differentiation on a torus

Tags: operator-theory, differential-operators, involutions

I'm trying to analyze [this article](http://arxiv.org/abs/1402.0070) about area-preserving diffeomorphisms and don't quite understand a sentence.

> 4.1. **Linear involutions.** We start characterizing the linear involutions $R \! : \mathbb{T}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb T^2$ of the torus, induced by
>   matrices $A$ in $\rm SL(2, \mathbb Z)$. After differentiating the equality $R^2 = Id_\mathbb{T^2}$ at any point of $\mathbb T^2$, we obtain $A^2 = Id_\mathbb{R^2}$.

This is from page 7.

How do they go from an operator defined on $\mathbb T^2$ to an operator defined on $\mathbb R^2$?

Just to be clear, a linear operator $R$ is called an involution, iff $R = R^{-1}$.

---

**EDIT**

Am I correct that you can represent an operator on a torus as an operator on the whole space $\rm mod$ something?

Comment: The torus $\mathbb{T}^2$ is defined as an abstract surface as $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$. So a map $f$ defined on the torus can be viewed as a map defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$ like this : $\forall\left(x,y\right)\in\mathbb{R}^2$, $\forall\left(k,\ell\right)\in\mathbb{Z}^{2}$, $f\left(x+k,y+\ell\right)= f\left(x,y\right)$.